# Python is running after windows 8.1 boot, why?

Tags: windows-8.1, python

I have several (3now, last time 1) processes of python which are present after windows boot. Why? Is it used by any program? How to get rid of this? I need memory unless I need python explicitly. I believe 2 and 3 versions are installed on the same machine with various software. From the SYSTEM user.

Comment: Uninstall Python and see what complains.

Comment: Isn't there a solution to just turn it off?

Comment: You could locate the executable(s) and rename them.

Comment: Load up Task Manager and go to the Startup tab. Find Python in the list, and disable it.

Comment: @JohnSmith You have presumably malicious software automatically starting (i.e software you don’t recognize installing) i asssumed Python was included and it wasn’t required.  You were not even sure Python was installed

Comment: Python was installed by me. I can see some kind of Python Launcher in installed programs list too.(I think it is not related) But I cannot see anything related to python in Task Manager, Startup tab. No python is there.